# How to fix “The specified blobdoes not exist. HTTP Status Code: 404 Error while using Start-AzStorageBlobCopy

Tags: azure, powershell, runtime-error, azure-blob-storage

I'm getting the error "The specified blob does not exist" running the `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` that copies a blob into another new blob in the same folder, the problem looks to be with that destination blob.

```
$sasKey = 'sv=2019-02-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=2020-06-07T20:40:57Z&st=2020-01-07T13:40:57Z&spr=https&sig=...'
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'my-storage-account' -SasToken $sasKey 
$context = $context.Context
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy `
        -Context $context `
        -SrcContainer 'labo' `
        -SrcBlob 'folder/document.txt' `
        -DestContainer 'labo' `
        -DestBlob 'folder/document2.txt' `
        -Force -Verbose
```

```
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy: The specified blob does not exist. HTTP Status Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified blob does not exist.
ErrorCode: CannotVerifyCopySource
ErrorMessage: The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:5ba3de1b-a01e-008f-4f35-f3644c000000
Time:2020-03-05T21:32:23.8622305Z
At line:5 char:1
    + Start-AzStorageBlobCopy `
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzStorageBlobCopy], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.StartAzureStorageBlobCopy
```

Comment: SAS must start with a ?     $sasKey = '?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&sr.....

Answer (score 0):

Just find an error in your script:

```
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'my-storage-account' -SasToken $sasKey 

# Should be $storageContext, not $context
$context = $storageContext .Context
```

Then, I test with the following script:

```
$sasKey = '?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-03-06T10:02:26Z&st=2020-03-06T02:02:26Z&spr=https,http&sig=tj1c***************************D'
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'storagetest789' -SasToken $sasKey 
$context = $storageContext.Context
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy `
        -Context $context `
        -SrcContainer 'test' `
        -SrcBlob 'hello/world.json' `
        -DestContainer 'pub' `
        -DestBlob 'hello/world.json' `
        -Force -Verbose
```

Result:

[image]

And, by checking in the storage account, the blob is successfully copied to destination container:

[image]

Comment: My bad, made that error when crafted the simplified test case, I still had the error after correction, but sow that your $sasKey starts with a "?", that's what was cussing the error in my case. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @AchilleSerdy I am glad that your problem has been solved. If it helps, could you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks